# Using the parent object in OnActivation() as an argument

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a component I am injecting with Ninject, and it has a member function that *must* be called after it is instantiated. I didn't put it in the constructor because it requires a reference to it's parent object and that would create a circular reference.

Currently, I just call the method in the *parent's* constructor, but it would be cleaner and less likely to be forgotten if I could have Ninject run the method for me.

Due to a lack of documentation, I have been fiddling with `OnActivation`, but can't seem to get it working.

Basically what I would like to do is:

```
    Bind<IMessageService>().To<QueuedMessageService>().InSingletonScope()
        .OnActivation((ctx, svc) => { svc.SubscribeAll(ctx.Request.Target); });
```

where `SubscribeAll(object target)`

AM I even on the right path or am I way out in left field? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IInitializable` interface:

```
public class Parent : Ninject.IInitializable
{
    private readonly IMessageService service;

    public Parent(IMessageService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        service.SubscribeAll(this);
    }
}
```

Initialize method will be called automatically by ninject.

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering if there is any way to accomplish this without hard coding a dependency to Ninject. Any ideas?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart, you can create your own interface and call `Initialize` method from `OnActivation` delegate on `Parent` binding.